# With React Navigation 5, how do I make navigating to a drawer item reset the state of that stack?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am using React Navigation v5 and have a drawer navigator whose screens are a bunch of stack navigators.

```js
    <AppDrawer.Navigator drawerContent={({navigation, state}) => <DrawerScreen navigation={navigation} state={state}/>}>
      <AppDrawer.Screen name="TodayStack" component={TodayStackComponent}/>
      <AppDrawer.Screen name="ClientsStack" component={ClientsStackComponent}/>
      <AppDrawer.Screen name="SettingsStack" component={SettingsStackComponent}/>
    </AppDrawer.Navigator>
```

In `DrawerScreen` (which is my custom override of the Drawer component), I have it currently navigating to each drawer item like this:

```
props.navigator.navigate('TodayStack')
```

That works fine in general.  However, I also want it to reset the stack state when you navigate from the drawer.  For example, I may have 3 stacked screens in the navigation history of `TodayStack`.  When I go to another drawer item, then tap back to `TodayStack`, I want it to reset back to the initial route for `TodayStack`'s navigator.

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Check out: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset

Comment: But how do I get access to the navigator for that stack inside the drawer navigator?

Comment: Where are you placing props.navigator.navigate('TodayStack') in the code? I have the same issue, except that I don't have control over what the onpress for the drawer.screen navigation is, How do I adjust what function fires when the user taps a sidedrawer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following:

import { CommonActions, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

then replace your code:

```
props.navigator.navigate('TodayStack')
```

with

```
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { name: 'TodayStack' },
    ],
  })
);
```

Comment: That worked great.  I had read the docs that explained that, but I misunderstood what the `routes` parameter was supposed to be.  :)  Thanks!